Can I copy all modified files of a RUN command into a new image layer?
I have a Dockerfile in which some linux packages are compiled from source.
The source code is multiple gigabytes in size while the build artifacts are only megabytes.
The package I compile builds and moves files in any possible directories in the file system like /etc or /lib. Since I am not the maintainer of that package I do not want to manually maintain a list of directories which contain build artifacts.
What I am looking for is an approach to keep only those modified or created files which are created by the build process which is essentially a RUN make step in the Dockerfile.
Below is a thought experiment which shows the general idea of what I want to archive.
Is there a Dockerfile machanism or usage pattern I should adaopt to archive what I have described above?
FROM ubuntu as build-layer

# 1. Clone source code - This increases the image size by Gigabytes
RUN git clone ...

# 2. Compile the package - This may create files in multiple, unknown directories (like /usr or /etc)
RUN --id=build-step make

FROM ubuntu as runtime-layer

# 3. Copy build artifacts
COPY --from=build-layer  --from-id=build-step

# The runtime-layer should now only be as large as the
# ubuntu image + the build artifacts generated by make install


I don't think there's a way to copy arbitrary layers separate from their history.  Can you control where files get installed, so you can use COPY --from normally?  For example, with the GNU Autoconf toolset you can ./configure --prefix=... to specify the installation directory, or a common Makefile pattern is to allow make install DESTDIR=... to put all of the installed files into a specific subdirectory.

I believe the feature has been requested a few times, but is not a capability of buildkit, yet. The best thing to do would be opening or commenting on an issue in moby/buildkit or docker/roadmap. E.g. moby/buildkit #4239 would probably solve this if implemented.
For doing this in your own builds, you can inspect the changes from a layer with a tool like wagoodman/dive and then ensure all of those files are copied as part of your build.
At a more advance level, if you wanted to build your own image manifests, this would be fairly straight forward, you would create a manifest without the git clone layer. My own tooling, regclient, even offers the ability to modify images after they have been output from the builder, so you could run:
regctl image mod --layer-rm-created-by 'git clone' $orig_image --create $new_iamge


I am already using dive for this purpose. What bugs me is that the package i compile installs itself in a lot of places and I can't really control that.
